# How to count number of occurrences of a specific list in a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, count, duplicates

Suppose that I have a list like this :

```
test=[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I count the number of occurrences of say the list [1, 0, 0, 0]?

Comment: please make an attempt before asking?

Answer (score 4):

Use `list.count`:

```
test.count([1,0,0,0])
```